# Script 'Game_Actor' line 335 (Cannot open menu in RPG Maker XP due to missing code?)

Tags: ruby, error-handling, game-development

I'm very new to coding. I've been using RPG Maker XP recently and have been able to fix most issues I've come across by Googling what needs to be done, however I seem to come across something I can't find an answer for.

I had deleted a class in the database (no script editing involved) so that I could rewrite it entirely, and when I finished and opened the game, I found a couldn't open the menu and the game shut down after showing this error message.

> Script 'Game_Actor' line 335 : NoMethodError occured.  Unable to find
>   method 'name' for nil:NilClass.

I looked at line 335 under the 'Game_Actor' window and saw this:

```
 return $data_classes[@class_id].name
```

As I've said, I know very little about code and so I can't actually see anything wrong with this. I didn't rewrite or edit any of the actual script so I'm not sure how I have affected the script. (I haven't touched any script on the principle I have no idea how to fix it.)

I have searched for answers but unfortunately most people seem to be using later version of the RPG Maker like Ace or MV, and they're different enough to XP that the answers are not relevant to this issue.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, or tell me how to fix this, I would be very appreciative. I've worked really hard on this project and I would hate to have to scrap it and start over.

Thanks again!

Comment: We need to see the whole game, post it on Github with the main file here if it's to long.

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly the error message sais that `$data_classes[@class_id]` is `nil` (and that's why `$data_classes[@class_id].name` is unavailable), so you have to check where it becomes `nil` and why. I'm afraid further help is impossible without you showing us more code of your app (presumably the full code).

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the code still tries to access the 'class' you deleted in the database. I take it you deleted a database table, is that right?

The error `Unable to find method 'name' for nil:NilClass.` means that the variable on which the code is trying access the method `name` is actually `nil`. The code expects it to contain an object instead.

From the look of it, `$data_classes[@class_id]` is a hash which is filled with definitions of 'classes'. It gets filled at some earlier point and since you did delete a class, it cannot find a definition for it.

Important here is that it still knows that it needs the class you deleted. It means this class is mentioned somewhere else before this hash initialization takes place. It might be in a config file or another 'class'. Without seeing the complete code it's hard to ponpoint where exactly.

If you cant find this location, try to restore the class you deleted and instead of deleting it altogether just remove anything from it that you don't need. This way the class itself will still be present and this error will not happen. You will be then able to add what you want in that class instead.